# Longest Arithmetic Progression Algorithm

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, interview-questions, dynamic-programming

**Problem Statement:**
>

> Given a sorted array, find the length of the longest arithmetic progression in it.
>
> Examples:
>   numbers = new int[]{1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}
>   The length is 5, and the sequence is 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 with increment 2 in each iteration.

**Introduction of the algorithm**

The longest arithmetic progressions algorithm can be solved using dynamic programming method. I spent several hours to study the algorithm. I read the paper called "[Finding Longest Arithmetic Progressions](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/pdf/arith.pdf)", base on the author's introduction in the paper, the lower bound algorithm is O(nlogn) based on the algebraic decision tree model of computation.  I will try to understand the lower bound algorithm later on, also I like to read the related question called [Longest equally-spaced subsequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159911/longest-equally-spaced-subsequence) on stackoverflow.com.

**Dynamic programming**

The longest arithmetic progression can be found in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time using a dynamic programming algorithm similar to the following interesting subproblem , which can be called AVERAGE.

**AVERAGE subproblem**

It is to determine whether the input contains a three-term arithmetic progression, or equivalently, if any array element is the average of two others.

**Test case analysis**

I like to use a 7 x 7 matrix to define the lookup table based on the test case {1,3,4,5,7,8,9}.

Base case is to set lookup[i][n-1] = 2 for any i from 0 to n - 1. 

       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
_________________________
0| 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2**
1| 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2**
2| 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2**
3| 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2**
4| 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2**
5| 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2**
6| 0 0 0 0 0 0 **2**

Checking out 8, found 7, 8, 9. We have lookup[4][5] = lookup[5][6] + 1. In other words, 8 is the average of 7 and 9, since 8 = (7 + 9)/ 2. This is also a simple example of **AVERAGE** subproblem. 


       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
_________________________
0| 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
1| 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
2| 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
3| 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
4| 0 0 0 0 0 **3** 2
5| 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
6| 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

The idea of applying test case analysis is to tutor myself to learn how to solve the algorithm using dynamic programming method step by step, later on I can apply this technique to other dynamic programming algorithm as well.

**Practice for mock interview**

I was told to practice this algorithm when I practice mock interviews February 18, 2018 weekend. I wrote a C# solution based on the above test case. The algorithm is not too hard, but it is hard for me to come out the idea to define the subproblem **AVERAGE** the first time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TwoPointerTechniques
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Based on the code from the following blog:
        /// https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Dynamic_Programming/Chapter_22_-_Longest_arithmetic_progression.jsp
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sortedArr = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 };
            var n = sortedArr.Length;
            var lookup = FindArithmeticProgressionLength3(sortedArr);

            Debug.Assert(lookup[0] == 5);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// How to find if a sorted array contains an Arithmetic Progression (AP) of length 3?
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numbers"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int[] FindArithmeticProgressionLength3(int[] numbers)
        {
            var n = numbers.Length;
            var lookup = new int[n][];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                lookup[i] = new int[n];
            }

            int maxAP = 2;

            int apTerm = 0;
            int apStart = 0;

            // Any 2-letter series is an AP
            // Here we initialize only for the last column of lookup because
            // all i and (n-1) pairs form an AP of size 2  
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                lookup[i][n - 1] = 2;
            }

            // Loop over the array and find two elements 'left' and 'right' such that 
            // numbers[left] + numbers[right] = 2 * numbers[middle]
            for (int middle = n - 2; middle >= 1; middle--)
            {
                var left = middle - 1;
                var right = middle + 1;

                while (left >= 0 && right <= n - 1)
                {
                    int isAP = (numbers[left] + numbers[right]) - 2 * numbers[middle];

                    if (isAP < 0)
                    {
                        right++;
                    }
                    else if (isAP > 0)
                    {
                        left--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lookup[left][middle] = lookup[middle][right] + 1;

                        maxAP = Math.Max(maxAP, lookup[left][middle]);

                        if (maxAP == lookup[left][middle])
                        {
                            // Store the Arithmetic Progression's term
                            // And the start point of the AP
                            apTerm = numbers[middle] - numbers[left];
                            apStart = left;
                        }

                        right++;
                        left--;
                    }
                }
            }

            return new int[] { maxAP, apStart, apTerm };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One of my motivation to ask the question is to provide helpful link for the algorithm as a mock interviewer. I plan to give the algorithm to the interviewee in mock interview one day, the interviewee likes to find a good web link to look up after the mock interview. To prepare this algorithm, I still miss the optimal solution based on the time complexity O(nlogn), the dynamic programming solution is not optimal in time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

In `FindArithmeticProgressionLength3` is always an array of dimension `n x n`. Why did you use jagged arrays instead of

```
var lookup = new int[n, n];

// several lines skipped ...

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    lookup[i, n - 1] = 2;
}
```

As an 2-dimensional array is only one object compared to n+1 objects with the jagged array you should consider using that. And also the risk of failing to initialize the array (either to forget one of the `lookup[n]` to allocate or an out-of-Memory exception) is reduced to one single line of Code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/92314)

Comment: @BenSteffan Actually, I think this is a perfectly valid point. While formulated as a question, it is a valid review point.

Comment: @SimonForsberg No, I disagree. Maybe there is a valid point of reasoning behind this, but since the answer does not attempt at all to explain why their solution is preferable, I fail to see how this constitutes a valid Code Review point. Imo, the first paragraph of "What goes into an answer in "[How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) applies here, in particular "Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review [...]".

Comment: @BenSteffan Seems like this answer has been fixed now which I hope brings the answer more to your liking. Although there is room for several other answers as well.